# Mailer not sending emails rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

My mailer is not sending anything after waiting and I am not sure why. I've tried `deliver_now` as well

When I go to the URL `http://localhost:3000/send_mail` I receive no errors and just a blank page.

my terminal states:

```
Started GET "/send_mail" for ::1 at 2014-11-18 00:32:39 -0800
Processing by HomeController#send_mail as HTML

ActionMailer::Base#mail: processed outbound mail in 1.2ms

Sent mail to myemail@gmail.com (1.2ms)
Date: Tue, 18 Nov 2014 00:32:39 -0800
From: me@example.com
To: myemail@gmail.com
Message-ID: <546b0427e5677_82b3ffd9e6809bc2363f@MTVL1289dd026.local.mail>
Subject: Contact request
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

test
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
::1 - - [18/Nov/2014:00:32:39 -0800] "GET /send_mail HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0066
```

config/environments/development.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  host = 'localhost:3000'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
```

home controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def send_mail
    ActionMailer::Base.mail(:from => "me@example.com", :to => "myemail@gmail.com", :subject => "Contact request", :body => "test").deliver
    render nothing: true
  end
end
```

routes.rb

`match '/send_mail', to: "home#send_mail", via: "get"`

Comment: `smtp_settings` set?

Comment: @Nithin shoot. I am learning Rails right now. I am not aware of this =[

Answer (score 1):

I have just copied my code from previous project

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            'mailme@gmail.com',
    password:             'pwd',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

check out. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried this however I am getting this error:`Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in HomeController#send_mail
534-5.7.9 Application-specific password required`

Comment: its a common issue, did any research? I once had to change password.

Comment: I asked around and it is due to this https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: just use gmail credentials it must do good, else change it to new 1 if you have above issue, use browser.